# VSTS: how to run tests from a different build after release?

Tags: automated-tests, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have two builds. One is the functional code that "does the work" (let's call it 'F') and the other one is automated tests (let's call it 'T'). The reason they're separate is basically that the two are using completely different technologies (T is C#/Mstest, F is something completely different).

What I want is to run, automatically, the tests from T whenever I release F into an environment, say integration.

I tried looking around (and googled --a lot!) but couldn't find a way to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two sets of [artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=vsts) to your release: One from build `F`, one from build `T`.

Comment: It worked. Well, sort of.

What you propose is definitely the way to go. But now I've run on a different issue: the release does not find any test dlls from project T.

It looks like the test dlls have not been published; probably the it's the same VSTS issue as this:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/7708

But in any case, your answer as correct. Thanks a lot.